# Creating another record from within the model: bad practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I have three models: Task, User, and Response.

When a user completes a task, the results is stored as a response. During that response time, a user is credited points.

My first question is, where should the logic for updating the points attribute go? Inside the Task, User, or Response model? Currently, I have it in the Response model, where it grabs Response.task.points and adds that value to User.task.points.

Response.create then looks like:

```
  # POST /responses
  # POST /responses.json
  def create
    @response = Response.new(response_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @response.save
        @response.reward_user

        format.html { redirect_to @response, notice: 'Response was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @response }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @response.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The second thing is that I want to log every points transaction. So I've created another model called points_transaction. My other question is, where should I create the points_transaction? In the Response.create controller? In the response model?

It seems wrong to create a PointsTransaction from within the Response create method, but it also seems equally wrong to create it from within the model. Which one is more MVC-correct?

My Response object looks like this:

```
class Response < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :task, optional: true
  belongs_to :user, optional: true

  def reward_user
    point_value = task.point_value
    user.points += point_value

    PointTransaction.new({/*params go here*/})
  end
end
```

Comment: You have a great question. I think you've reached a point, when you need to move onto the next level of your architecture solutions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach to this type of problem is to create service object which can wrap all of the processing code into one 'unit' of code.  You will let the service object check the `Response` and then update the user's points and track the `PointTransaction` so that you can keep your controller skinny and you can prevent your models from touching other models or producing other side effects that may be unclear.

Let's assume you create a folder names services inside of the app directory and you put your service class in there.

```ruby
# app/services/response_checker.rb
class ResponseChecker
  attr_reader :success

  def initialize
  end

  def call(response, task, user)
    @success = if response.save
      user.points += task.point_value
      point_trans = PointTransaction.new(/*params go here*/)

      user.save && point_trans.save
    else 
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Then, use the service in your controller:

```
# app/controllers/response_controller.rb
def create
  @response = Response.new(response_params)
  @response_checker = ResponseChecker.new.call(@response, @response.task, @response.user)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @response_checker.success
      # conditional controller response logic
    end
  end
end
```

You may want to create an errors attribute on the service object to capture information about errors during the execution of the service and then expose them to who/whatever is using the service (the controller in this case).

Comment: Quick question. What is the purpose of the initialize function? What should I pass in as initialized variables versus in the call?

Comment: I put the `initialize` method in to be clear that it really isn't doing anything special here.  We could leave it out and everything would still work the same.  There are some different takes on exactly how to instantiate and interact with services, but one way that I like is to use `new`/`initialize` to inject any other service-type dependencies that might be needed, and use `call` to pass in the objects with the state that we need to use to do the work. It is easier to test this way.  Some examples here:  https://hackernoon.com/going-further-with-service-objects-in-ruby-on-rails-b8aac13a7271

Answer (score 1):

I think you definitely faced a situation, when you need to go beyond simple **MVC**.

Firstly, in ideal world models shouldn't know about each other at all. So you shouldn't refer any other models from `Response` as you do. On the other hand... controller is definitely even worse, then putting it into model.

Secondly, if you have doubts where to put your code between 2 places. Then both of them is not good enough and you need to look for third one.

That's when **service objects** came to the game. It's pretty widely spread and common pattern in rails. I am not sure whether it's perfect solution, but it decouple your code, keep your code clean and easy testable. I haven't found any issues with such approach yet, except having too many service objects :).

Here is a sample with logic, that touches several models from our project (app/services/active_site_service.rb):

```
class ActivateSiteService
  attr_reader :error

  def initialize(user, template, password)
    @user = user
    @template = template
    @activation = @user.activation_for(@template)
    @password = password
  end

  def call
    return false unless self.valid?

    generate_site_service = GenerateSiteService.new(@user, @template)
    generate_site_service.call

    @activation.update(quantity: @activation.quantity - 1)

    @user.transactions.create(status: :success,
                              target: generate_site_service.site,
                              amount: 0,
                              transaction_type: :site_activation)
    true
  end

  protected
  def valid?
    validate_password && validate_activation
  end

  def validate_password
    return true if @user.valid_password?(@password)
    @error = 'Неправильный пароль'
    false
  end

  def validate_activation
    return true if @activation.present? && @activation.quantity > 0
    @error = 'У вас нет предоплаченных активаций'
    false
  end
end
```

Rules, that we follow:

1. Conceptually service object is a business process, which include several models
2. Name always start with a verb
3. Service object has only 2 methods: `initialize` and `call`
4. `call` always return only true/false
5. Only 2 `attr_reader` variable allowed -- `result` to get some data or object from service or `error` to get an error

Controller:

```
class ActivationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    template = Site.templates.find(params[:template_id])

    activate_site_service = ActivateSiteService.new(current_user, template, params[:password])

    if activate_site_service.call
      redirect_to sites_path, notice: 'Активация сайта прошла успешно'
    else
      redirect_to new_purchase_path(template_id: template.id), alert: activate_site_service.error
    end
  end
end
```

If you can't fall into these rules, then it's mostly NOT a service object. You can google more about service objects

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. Where would the service model go? In lib?

Comment: Also, who calls the service object? Should the service object be another controller? Or should I call it from Response.create? Meaning that it will log the response and reward the user as an atomic operation from within Response?

Comment: Included everything to my answer. Why I would not go with lib. Lib is mostly a module that is a separate library and can be used in other projects. So for me lib is mostly like technical helper and never has any relation to business logic. Everything related to business logic should go into `app/` folder